# Does anyone know how to fix this error in Netbeans 19 to install JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am getting this below error when trying to install and activiate JavaFX in Netbeans 19.

```
There were some problems while storing JavaFX Implementation for Windows (amd64).
Cause: Cannot resolve external reference to [m2:/org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.7:jar:win]
```

Any help to resolve this error is much appreciated. I am using Netbeans on Windows 10.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also check your Netbeans > Settings > Java > Maven > Maven Home.

Comment: Follow tutorial: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 1):

It looks you don't have openjfx library in your local Maven repository.
Try to add following dependency to your dependencies section in pom.xml file.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

PS. [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) is great tool to look for missing dependencies.